# Moving pebbles and invariable state

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ pebbles divided into small heaps. For each step, one pebble from each heap is taken to form a new heap. I need to prove that no matter what state one start with, eventually the number of pebbles from each heap is $1, 2, ..., n.$
For example, when $n=5$

$(7,8) \rightarrow (6,7,2) \rightarrow (5,6,1,3) \rightarrow (4,5,2,4) \rightarrow (3,4,1,3,4) \rightarrow (2,3,2,3,5) \rightarrow (1,2,1,2,4,5) \rightarrow (1,1,3,4,6) \rightarrow (2,3,5,5) \rightarrow (1,2,4,4,4) \rightarrow (1,3,3,3,5) \rightarrow (2,2,2,4,5) \rightarrow (1,1,1,3,4,5) \rightarrow (2,3,4,6) \rightarrow (1,2,3,5,4)$

I have try to construct a state function that decreases for each operation. I also draw a digraph for case $n=3$ but I did not recognized any particular pattern.